# How to Use Cloud Storage Fuse to backup files when deleted in local machine

Tags: google-cloud-storage, fuse, gcsfuse

I installed gcsfuse on my local macOS system and mounted a folder to cloud storage bucket.
everythings works fine.

but, If deleted a file from mounted folder also deleting on bucket.
I don't want this to be happen.

when ever I delete any files, It should only delete on my local machine.

Can anyone help me to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with official version of gcsfuse.

As workaround, you can activate the [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning). Thereby, even is you delete a file, a versioned copy still live in your Bucket. You lost nothing.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HSnyu0_nBg) is also great for explaining the versioning

If you really want to use gcsfuse with your special feature, you can fork the project and remove the  delete part in the code of the [open source project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse)